# reinterpret_cast of an object

Tags: c++, casting, compilation, reinterpret-cast

Taking this struct:

```
struct Foo
{
    float m_foo;
    // no other member
};

// A Foo object.
Foo f;
```

Which is more costly?

```
float result = std::sin(f.m_foo);
```

or

```
float result = std::sin(*(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&f)));
// f can be interpreted like float in this case
```

I think the second case is faster, but i don't have sure because i don't know how the compiler will handle it. What you can tell me about it?

Comment: Do ***measurements*** before thinking such things. Also, it depends on the compiler and optimisation settings.

Comment: Or even better, look at the assembly. I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler produces the exact same code for both versions

Comment: @RadekSlupik This is the case. I don't know how to measure this. I need help on this. I want to know what the compiler does with it.

Comment: @LucasNunes run both a billion times in a loop and check which loop took longer to finish.

Comment: @NiklasB. What program can I use to see this?

Comment: @LucasNunes your compiler. For GCC and clang, use the `-S` flag.

Comment: @RadekSlupik I measured the two cases 4000000000 times. But it's strange, same times the first win and other the second win. And if i compile in release mode doesn't work: http://pastebin.com/1PtRkEB6

Comment: @LucasNunes: why do you care? `sin` an order of magnitude slower then the member access unless there is a cache miss, which would hit both versions equally. Therefore optimizing it is premature optimization. Furthermore most compilers will probably compile both versions to the same code. If they do not it is obviously compiler dependent (and compiler version), which one is faster. Therefore this is premature optimization which might be worthless with the next version of the compiler. So again why bother?

Comment: @Grizzly It's just for curiosity and experience. I'm not using it in any project. I really agree with you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which is more costly?

IME, the one invoking ***Undefined Behavior*** is always more costly in the end.

If you want to port this to some new platform, or another compiler, or a new version of your compiler, ***such code might blow up***. Or it might make some other, innocent looking code blow up. Or it might do so only on Sundays, when your customers cannot call support. (They will call on Monday then, so you should take off on Monday as often as possible if you write such code.) Or it might only do so when your boss is around, or at full moon, or at compiler versions built at the first of the month.

If you have some ***concrete case*** where you need to speed up some code, and you found, ***through profiling***, that this piece of code is a bottleneck, then ***measure whether this brings any relevant performance advantages***, ***using your real application*** and real data. If it does, then in God's name use it *in this one place*, but put some very visible comment there, explaining what you do and why.

Comment: I liked the version with less emphasis more :D

Comment: @NiklasB: It's my answer, so you will have to endure my spleens. `:)`

Comment: @NiklasB. The emphasis makes it correct and hilarious at the same time. My money goes on the emphatic version!

Comment: Is it really undefined behaviour? `Foo` is POD and according to `§9.2.21` in the c++11 standard: `a pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitable converted using a reinterpret_cast points to its initial member`. Therefore I don't see how the code in the question is UB (there is obviously little reason to use such a code, but that's beside the point).

Comment: @Grizzly: It might very well not be. I am not a language lawyer, after all. However, nor are 99% of the people who will look at that code, and have to decide whether it's to be blamed for the application blowing up after compiling it with the new compiler version. And all for an "optimization" that very likely isn't one.